# Pandas Dataframe Processing is Very Slow

Tags: python, pandas

I am working on a dataset which contains a datetime column and a variable which I'm insterested in. What I wanted to do was group the data into 15 minute groups, so I wrote the following code which basically calculates a lower and upper date bounds and creates a list of datetime objects with 15 minutes intervals. Then sums the variable I'm interested between each pair of datetime objects and puts the sum in a new dataframe. But it runs very slow (it took about five hours to process 75000 rows) and I can't figure out why. Can anybody point what is wrong with the code?

[here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=19GzQZ9_bhYIVYui7sFbCFbptyKmLVvFq) is a small sample data if you want to test the code for yourself.

```
def create_sales_with_intervals(df, tank_id_col='tank_id'): 
    tank_id = df.iloc[0][tank_id_col]
    tank_dates = get_date_range(df)
    tank_sales =[]

    for idx in tnrange(len(tank_dates) - 1):
        t1 = tank_dates[idx]
        t2 = tank_dates[idx+1]

        sales = get_sales_between(df, t1, t2)

        row={}
        row['start_date'] = t1
        row['end_date'] = t2
        row['total_sale'] = sales
        row['tank_id'] = tank_id
        tank_sales.append(row)

    return pd.DataFrame(tank_sales, columns=['tank_id', 'start_date', 'end_date', 'total_sale'])


def get_date_range(df_tank, date_col='date_time', freq='15MIN'):
    start_date = df_tank.iloc[0][date_col]
    end_date = df_tank.iloc[-1][date_col]

    lower_bound = find_interval(start_date, 'lower')
    upper_bound = find_interval(end_date, 'upper')

    start_date_rounded = round_time(start_date, lower_bound) # Rounds the minute portion of the datetime object to nearest lower bound (0, 15, 30 , 45)
    end_date_rounded = round_time(end_date, upper_bound) # Rounds the minute portion of the datetime object to nearest upper bound (0, 15, 30 , 45)

    tank_dates = pd.date_range(start_date_rounded, end_date_rounded, freq=freq)
    return tank_dates

def get_sales_between(df, t1, t2, date_col='date_time', sale_col='sold'):
    cond1 = df[df[date_col] > t1]
    cond2 = df[df[date_col] < t2]

    idx = cond1.index & cond2.index
    total_sale = df.loc[idx.values][sale_col].sum()
    return total_sale
```

Comment: Can you provide some data for testing / benchmarking? We don't need all 75000 rows, but 10 might suffice.

Comment: [here](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/69MZdMmGh4/) is a sample data. Just copy and paste it into a text editor and save it as csv

Comment: Sorry, here on SO we treat questions / answers as a resource for *all* users. Therefore, please post some representative data with the question itself, not as a link (or image).

Comment: So I added a link to a sample dataset in question. I would attach the file but I think file upload is not supported by SO. Here is an [answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/335568/4638103) about uploading csv files which says upload file and share the link in question.

Comment: Well, unfortunately I can't access the above link. Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following which uses the `pd.DataFrame.resample()` method when you have a `DatetimeIndex`:

```
# your sample dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'date_time': {0: '2015-01-02 23:18:00',
                      1: '2015-01-03 01:00:00',
                      2: '2015-01-03 02:42:00',
                      3: '2015-01-03 04:24:00',
                      4: '2015-01-03 06:06:00',
                      5: '2015-01-03 07:48:00',
                      6: '2015-01-03 09:30:00',
                      7: '2015-01-03 11:12:00',
                      8: '2015-01-03 12:54:00',
                      9: '2015-01-03 14:36:00'},
         'sold': {0: 78.3,
                  1: 0.0,
                  2: 112.9,
                  3: 13.8,
                  4: 32.0,
                  5: 95.1,
                  6: 56.4,
                  7: 28.3,
                  8: 0.0,
                  9: 0.0},
         'tank_id': {0: 1, 1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 1, 4: 1, 5: 1, 6: 1, 7: 1, 8: 1, 9: 1}
    })


df
Out[3]: 
             date_time  sold  tank_id
0  2015-01-02 23:18:00  78.3        1
1  2015-01-03 01:00:00     0        1
2  2015-01-03 02:42:00 112.9        1
3  2015-01-03 04:24:00  13.8        1
4  2015-01-03 06:06:00    32        1
5  2015-01-03 07:48:00  95.1        1
6  2015-01-03 09:30:00  56.4        1
7  2015-01-03 11:12:00  28.3        1
8  2015-01-03 12:54:00     0        1
9  2015-01-03 14:36:00     0        1

# convert your timestamps to `pd.Timestamp` objects
df['date_time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date_time'])

# give the dataframe a `DatetimeIndex`
df.set_index('date_time', inplace=True)

df
Out[6]: 
                     sold  tank_id
date_time                         
2015-01-02 23:18:00  78.3        1
2015-01-03 01:00:00     0        1
2015-01-03 02:42:00 112.9        1
2015-01-03 04:24:00  13.8        1
2015-01-03 06:06:00    32        1
2015-01-03 07:48:00  95.1        1
2015-01-03 09:30:00  56.4        1
2015-01-03 11:12:00  28.3        1
2015-01-03 12:54:00     0        1
2015-01-03 14:36:00     0        1

# resample the `sold` column in 15 minuTe chunks and then sum each chunk
df['sold'].resample('15T').sum()
Out[8]: 
date_time
2015-01-02 23:15:00    78.3
2015-01-02 23:30:00       0
2015-01-02 23:45:00       0
2015-01-03 00:00:00       0
2015-01-03 00:15:00       0
2015-01-03 00:30:00       0
2015-01-03 00:45:00       0
2015-01-03 01:00:00       0
2015-01-03 01:15:00       0
2015-01-03 01:30:00       0
2015-01-03 01:45:00       0
2015-01-03 02:00:00       0
2015-01-03 02:15:00       0
2015-01-03 02:30:00   112.9
2015-01-03 02:45:00       0
2015-01-03 03:00:00       0
2015-01-03 03:15:00       0
2015-01-03 03:30:00       0
2015-01-03 03:45:00       0
2015-01-03 04:00:00       0
2015-01-03 04:15:00    13.8
2015-01-03 04:30:00       0
2015-01-03 04:45:00       0
2015-01-03 05:00:00       0
2015-01-03 05:15:00       0
2015-01-03 05:30:00       0
2015-01-03 05:45:00       0
2015-01-03 06:00:00      32
2015-01-03 06:15:00       0
2015-01-03 06:30:00       0

2015-01-03 07:15:00       0
2015-01-03 07:30:00       0
2015-01-03 07:45:00    95.1
2015-01-03 08:00:00       0
2015-01-03 08:15:00       0
2015-01-03 08:30:00       0
2015-01-03 08:45:00       0
2015-01-03 09:00:00       0
2015-01-03 09:15:00       0
2015-01-03 09:30:00    56.4
2015-01-03 09:45:00       0
2015-01-03 10:00:00       0
2015-01-03 10:15:00       0
2015-01-03 10:30:00       0
2015-01-03 10:45:00       0
2015-01-03 11:00:00    28.3
2015-01-03 11:15:00       0
2015-01-03 11:30:00       0
2015-01-03 11:45:00       0
2015-01-03 12:00:00       0
2015-01-03 12:15:00       0
2015-01-03 12:30:00       0
2015-01-03 12:45:00       0
2015-01-03 13:00:00       0
2015-01-03 13:15:00       0
2015-01-03 13:30:00       0
2015-01-03 13:45:00       0
2015-01-03 14:00:00       0
2015-01-03 14:15:00       0
2015-01-03 14:30:00       0
Freq: 15T, Name: sold, Length: 62, dtype: float64
```

You can find more info in the `pandas` docs [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#resampling).